# Call Hierarchy of a method programatically not using eclipse shortcut

Tags: java, call-hierarchy

I saw a similar post from one of the page of stackoverflow

[Using Search Engine to implement call hierarchy (getting all the methods that invoke a certain method) in Java/eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980726/using-search-engine-to-implement-call-hierarchy-getting-all-the-methods-that-in/62189307#62189307)

But the code on usage holds a method findMethod. What is type in that method argument. Please suggest a code having that argument value.

```
IMethod m = findMethod(type, "world");
Set<IMethod> methods = new HashSet<IMethod>();
methods = callGen.getCallersOf(m);
for (Iterator<IMethod> i = methods.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
{
    System.out.println(i.next().toString());
}
```

Comment: Nice question! Would love to see a detailed explanation with a solution.

Comment: Didn't quite catch what you mean? In the post you reference the `findMathod` is there in code with arguments `findMethod(IType, String)`

Comment: I need values of those arguments, as IType is an interface and I am not as good in those concepts. I need what needs to be passed in that IType argument.