# Retrieving information of all the callers of method in java

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to get information of all the caller of specific method of class programmatically and came across solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13993455/6161431). But as per latest release of the project org.eclipse.jdt.ui (3.21) consisting those classes used in above example are not present. The classes were part till 3.13 release.
Are those classes refactored or removed because of defects introduced?

Comment: Look into the Git repository: https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/

Comment: The internal classes still exist but have restricted access. These are internal classes which are not intended for general use, they can change at any time.

Comment: I've checked the repository howlger, however I'm using maven project and couldn't find those classes at all in the jar for 3.21